# How to display Annotation view without clicking on pin in mapview?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented one map application in which i have display pin animation for current location.When i click on the pin at that time annotation view will open. But i want to display
annotation view without clicking on pin.Is it possible if possible then please give me idea about that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Try out:

It seems that `[mapView selectAnnotation:annotation animated:YES]` works too.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to find your MKAnnotationView instance you want to select and call `-setSelected:animated:`.

For example, you can loop your annotations of an MKMapView like this:

```
for (YOURCLASSHERE *a in mapView.annotations) {
    // Your current position (if shown) is an annotation as well. Thus check for the right class!
    if ([a isKindOfClass:[YOURCLASSHERE class]]) {
        // insert some smart if statement here, if you have multiple annotations!
        [[mapView viewForAnnotation:a] setSelected:YES animated:YES];
    }
}
```

YOURCLASSHERE is your class which implements the `MKAnnotation` protocol.

Of course the loop is superfluous if you already know your annotationView.

Answer (score -2):

We can show the annotation with out clicking on it. Use the following code:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{
     static NSString *identifier = @"Pin";

    MKPinAnnotationView *pin = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    pin.canShowCallout = YES;
    [pin setSelected:YES animated:NO];

    return [pin autorelease];
}
```

Comment: There is a memory leak in your code and it is definitely not the recommended way to implement the delegate method. You will want to reuse existing annotationViews for performance reasons.